# Date Validation and Conversion in C++

Tags: c++

I have to write 2 functions. One that takes in a date as a string and checks if its in mm/dd/yy format; if its not in the correct format, it should be edited to make it so. The other function should convert the validated date to the format "Month dd, 20yy".

I'm pretty sure I can take care of the second function, but I am having trouble with the first one. I just have no idea how to check if its in that format... any ideas?

<s>I thought that this would work, but it doesn't seem to...</s>

Updated code:

```
bool dateValidation(string shipDate)
{
    string temp;
    if(shipDate.length() == 8 )
    {
        if(shipDate[2] == '/' && shipDate[5] =='/')
        {
            int tempDay, tempMonth, tempYear;
            //Gather month
            temp = shipDate[0];
            temp += shipDate[1];
            //convert string to int
            tempMonth = temp.atoi;
            temp = "";

            //Gather day
            temp = shipDate[3];
            temp += shipDate[4];
            //convert string to int
            tempDay = temp.atoi;
            temp = "";

            //Gather year
            temp = shipDate[6];
            temp += shipDate[7];
            //convert string to int
            tempYear = temp.atoi;
            temp = "";

            if(tempMonth > 0 && tempMonth <= 12)
            {

                if(tempMonth == 9 ||
                   tempMonth == 4 ||
                   tempMonth == 6 ||
                   tempMonth == 11 ||)
                {
                    if(tempDay > 0 && tempDay <= 30)
                    {
                        if 30 days
                            }
                }
                else if(tempMonth == 2)
                {
                    if(tempDay > 0 && tempDay <= 28)
                    {
                        if 28 days
                            }
                }
                else
                {
                    if(tempDay > 0 && tempDay <= 31)
                    {
                        if 31 days
                            }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why doesn't it work, what is the problem? Also what sort of variations can the date come in, could it come like this: 101112 or does it always have something between the d/m/y also can m and d and y be swapped around?

Comment: I just hit a wall. I redid it like 20 times, and this is where I stopped last. Its not complete here. I need some help writing it. :/

Comment: You are not actually validating that the values are correct.. just checking punctuation..

Comment: Exactly, how do I even validate it?

Comment: How about [regular expressions](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex)? And if your compiler and library isn't new enough for C++11 regexes, then check [Boost regex](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/libs/regex/doc/html/index.html).

Comment: You are grabbing the 3 components in the last segment of the code, just check if they are valid values

Comment: I updated the code. What does everyone think? On the right track? 

@JoachimPileborg That sounds like gibberish to me, but I am open to learning, as long as it isn't too complicated. My teacher probably won't approve of it if it is TOO complicated.

Comment: Regex `(\d){1,2}(-|\\|/)(\d){1,2}(-|\\|/)(\d){4}`

Comment: @vidit I have no idea what any of that means... I'm not that far into C++; I'm halfway through my first course.

Comment: @JoshI - Its a regular expression, used for finding and matching patterns. It is not part of any language per se, but almost all language support them. Joachim above posted a link on how you can use it in C++

Comment: @vidit I don't think my teacher would approve of this, as we are just doing relatively simple things. I think I have some of it fixed above. What do you think?

Answer (score 0):

There are 4 things you want to check:

- Is there 8 characters ? If not, then don't even bother checking anything else. It's not in the proper format.
- Are the third and fifth characters '/'. If not, then you still don't have the proper format.
- Check each pair for its valid values. A month has days between 1 and
  31 at most, there are no more than 12 months and months range from 01
  to 12. A year can be any combination of any 2 digits.

This should take care of the format, but if you want to make sure that the date is valid:

- Check for valid number of days in each month (january 31, february
  28-29...) and indeed check for those leap years.

Comment: I thought the same thing, but there is one problem. Technically 1/1/2012 is a valid date, but using this psuedocode, it is not. I would have to come up with some way to turn "1" into "01" and "2012" to "12".

Answer (score 0):

This looks a lot like a project I am about to grade.... You should verify that it is Gregorian Calendar compliant if it is the project I am about to grade.  1/1/2012 is definitely valid though so what you may want to do and what I would hope you consider is creating a switch statement that examines for formats like 1/12/2012 and 10/2/2012 because these are valid. Then parse out the month day and year from these. Then verify that they are within the limit of the Gregorian calendar. If it is for a class which I would guess that it is, you should consider writing the verification as a separate function from the parsing function.

So first ask whether the date is too long if not, is it too short, if not which version is it, then pass the d m y to the verification function. This kind of modularity will simplify your code and reduce instructions.

something like

bool dateValidation(string shipDate)
{
     string temp;

```
switch(shipDate.length())
{
     case(10):
        // do what  your doing
        verify(m,d,y);
        break;

     case(8):
        //dealing with single digits
        // verify 1 and 3 are '/' and the rest are numbers
        verifiy(m,d,y);
        break;

     case(9):
        //a little more heavy lifting here 
        // but its good thinking for a new programmer
        verifiy(m,d,y);
        break;
     default:       

      //fail message
        break;
}
```